# How can I change a user's Twitter name with a bot?

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am trying to find out if there's a way to change your Twitter name with software.
What I'm trying to make is a program that every day decrements a number in my name.

For example, on October 3 my name might be "Spam - 5" but on October 4 it might be "Spam - 4".

Preferably done with Python 2.7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a [Twitter Application](https://apps.twitter.com/) associated with your account to get the required OAuth keys.

Using [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter):

```
import time, twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='CONSUMER_KEY_HERE', consumer_secret='CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE', access_token_key='ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE', access_token_secret='ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_HERE')

i = 0
while True:
    api.UpdateProfile(name=str(i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(60 * 60 * 24) # 1 day
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using the Twitter module, it's giving me an ImportError with request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `POST account/update_profile` API endpoint to update your twitter username. See [the relevant documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile) for details.